# All devices on my Team Viewer have dissapeared

Tags: teamviewer

I have 3 mining rigs and all of them were connected to my Team Viewer 12 account so I can monitor them.
Yesterday I installed Team Viewer 13 on my laptop and connected it to my account and then all mining rigs have disappeared.
Is there any way to reconnect mining rigs to my profile without need to connect monitor, keyboard and mouse to my rigs and then connect each of them again to profile.

Comment: You should roll back to Team Viewer 12, then upgrade each of the machines to Team Viewer 13, then install Team Viewer 13 on the laptop.

Comment: @Ramhound so there is no way to solve issue without  doing something on mining rigs? P.S. Thank you for that advice

Answer (score 0):

I'm still on Version 11 and won't even try to get off that version.  I tried upgrading ONE PC once, to version 12, and then I couldn't connect to it ever again, unless I upgraded ANY PCs that were using that version.  I suspect that versions 12, 13, etc., work the same way.

Rule -- Whatever versions you install, SAVE the installation EXE, since you might have to revert back to that version.  In my one test, I simply re-installed a version 11 EXE installation that I still had, (not even the latest in the 11.x series builds), and then everything worked again on ALL the PCs.

Be careful you don't get a bogus copy of TV install if downloading from somewhere.  TV doesn't seem to make old versions available.

Personally, I like V11.x and it does what I need just fine.  So, I just always turn off updates whenever I install.